# Error: The selector did not select any valid DOM element. Please check on which element you called AutoNumeric

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using AutoNumeric library in my Vue js application, but I always get this error in console 
`Error: The selector did not select any valid DOM element. Please check on which element you called AutoNumeric`

I'm using AutoNumeric in this way:

1. I did npm install autonumeric --save
2. I have this component One.vue

```
<b-form-input type="text" class="my-input"></b-form-input>

<script>
import AutoNumeric from 'autonumeric';
export default {
    mounted() {
        new AutoNumeric('#my-input', {
            decimalCharacter: ",",
            digitGroupSeparator: "."
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are using an id selector, but your element has `my-input` as a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#my-input : .my-input
```

since it is the class not id so you have to change it